# Count how many random 1s per turn in an array of initial 0s

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Imagine I have an array of N booleans with value 0. And in each turn I set one of them to 1 with equal probability. Is there any function that describes the average number of 1s per X turns?.

At start, if the N is big it would increase linearly up to a point where there are a lot more 1s than zeroes, after that it will do a curved line as the chance to set 1 on a 0 cell would decrease a lot as the amount of 0 cells decreases. It may have something to do with markov chains if i am not mistaken.

The function would kinda look like this $$f(x)=N(1-\frac{1}{g(x)}),\quad g(x)=1+x $$

but I cant figure out any hidden parameters or a better function than g(x), or even a complete different function than f(x)

Comment: On the first turn, all of the booleans are at $0$, so of course you change a zero to a $1$ here.  On a later turn however... are you always guaranteed to have picked a $0$ to turn into a $1$?  Or is it possible to have picked a $1$ in which case effectively nothing happens?

Comment: This is known as the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), and searching for that term may help you find useful information.

Comment: A common approach to this and similar problems would be since you are looking simply for the *average* (*i.e. expected number*) of the total number of $1$'s and not explicitly the probability distribution function itself, to approach using the linearity of expectation.  Look at the probability that after $X$ turns that specifically the *first* element in your array ended up as a $1$.  Your result will be $N$ times that.

Comment: "*in each turn I set one of them to 1*" do you actually mean "in each turn I swap the value of one boolean" or do you mean that if the selected boolean is already $1$ it stays at $1$?

Comment: I just set to 1, if it has a 1 nothing changes by setting it to 1 again edit: yes it is the same as coupon collector's problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we initially had $n$ zeroes, and on turn $t$ we already have $K_t$ ones. Then we have, that $K_{t+1} = K_t$ with probability $\frac{K_t}{n}$ and $K_{t+1} = K_t + 1$ with probability $1 - \frac{K_t}{n}$.

Thus, for every fixed of $K_t = c$ we have, that $$E[K_{t+1}] = \frac{c^2}{n} + c + 1 - \frac{c^2}{n} - \frac{c}{n} = c(1 - \frac{1}{n}) + 1$$ From that we can derive the following recurrent formula for $E[K_t]$:

$$E[K_0] = 0$$
$$E[K_{t+1}] = E[K_t](1-\frac{1}{n}) + 1$$

From this it follows, that

$$E[K_{t}] = \sum_{i = 0}^{t-1} (1 - \frac{1}{n})^i = \frac{1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^t}{1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})} = n\Big(1 - \big(1 - \frac{1}{n}\big)^t\Big)$$

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks a lot! Is there any way to describe this formula into a non recursive function? I think it would be something like the inverse of $$f(x)=n\sum_{i=0}^{x}{\frac{1}{n-i}}\quad or f(x)=n(H_n\times H_{n-x}), \quad 0<x<n$$

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης, I have edited the question. Now it contains this function in a closed form (without both recursion and even summation).

Comment: excellent, some people gave me the inverse problem (coupon collector's) and I was trying to invert the functions provided in the problem, I found the inverse for the full array of 1s which is:
$$f(x)=\frac{x-0.5}{W_0(e^\gamma(x-0.5))}$$
where gamma is the Euler–Mascheroni constant and W the Lambert W function.
That describes as f(x) the length of the array that would be fully filled by 1s if given x turns. But it doesn't do for a subset of the array that has 1s as your equation does for the n and t variables. You can check that for n=8196 and t=78588, your E[Kt] is similar to my f(78588)